# Https server with self signed certificate

Tags: node.js, https

After creating a self signed certificate, after turning insecure localhost on in chrome:
chrome://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost

and after adding the self signed certificate system and 'trust all'. The below code still doesn't host a server over https. 
The following error is shown in chrome:

> ```
> This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> localhost sent an invalid response.
> Try running Network Diagnostics.
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
> ```

What am I missing for this to work?

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var app = express();

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(8000);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8001);
```

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct port? `https://localhost:8001/...`

Comment: yes I'm surfing to https: //localhost:8001/

Comment: Is your certificate's CN 'localhost'?  i.e. `CN=localhost`

Comment: @wablab tried this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating the certificate(followed http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html) and adding it to keychain access worked for me on mac

```
    openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024   
    openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr
    cp server.key server.key.org
    openssl rsa -in server.key.org -out server.key
    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt
```

Comment: These steps for Mac made a trick after 2 hours of searching Internet. Thanks @Vincent! I was using https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/ instructions before and steps for certificate didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when i accidentally wiped my openssl-serial file. All certs issued from then on started with serials that had already been issued. If a client takes note of a certificate with a serial that has already been seen by this client, the cert won't be accepted at all and the connection will not be established.

Although I don't know if that's the issue (maybe you trace your log for the detailled error).